# Is the score function in Langevin dynamics related to the informant (score)?

Tags: likelihood, fisher-information, diffusion, langevin-diffusion

In Langevin dynamics and diffusion models we see the *score* $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\log p(\mathbf{x})$.
Here the notation seems to suggest we're taking partial derivatives w.r.t the free $\mathbf{x}$ variables in the support of $p$. And diagrams ([see the section on Langevin dynamics](https://yang-song.net/blog/2021/score/)) show arrows in a vector field superimposed on the density pointing to areas of higher density.

But elsewhere, *score* (or the *informant*) is also defined as $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log\mathcal{L}(\theta)$ i.e the gradient of the log likelihood w.r.t the *parameters* that describe the shape of the distribution, e.g mean, standard deviation etc. I see no way to visualize this in the same way as the previous score, so it seems like a distinct concept.

Am I correct? Are these two punned, or are they related in some way?